# Respecting API availability in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm currently working on adding support for the Touch Bar to Transmission. The fork is [here](https://github.com/michaelsavich/transmission) although you probably don't need to read it to answer this question.

Right now the code runs fine on 10.12, but of course it crashes on versions without the Touch Bar API. There are methods of working around this like respondsToSelector and ifdef, but those don't apply to IB, which is where I laid out the Touch Bar.

How do I get my interface builder file, with the Touch Bar layout inside it, to work on older versions of macOS? Do I just have to bite the bullet and do all the Touch Bar stuff in code?

Comment: Why not use preprocessor directives or something similar to handle it?

Comment: You mean put #ifdef inside the IB file?

Comment: Create it programmatically after window has been initialised.

Comment: @Astoria so what you're saying is that I should ditch IB in this case?

Comment: If your deployment target is earlier than 10.12.1, Interface Builder compiles the nib twice, both with and without Touch Bar elements. You should see `keyedobjects.nib` and `keyedobjects-101201.nib` within the compiled nib file. If you are still getting a crash, please file a radar at bugreport.apple.com, and attach the crash log and details about which document is causing the crash.

Comment: This is the confirmation I'm looking for. It could be that the build crashed on the target machine for entirely unrelated reasons, I don't have an older Mac to test on so I borrowed one for 30 seconds. I need to find someone who will let me install Xcode and view the logs…